# Tumblr Custom VideoThumbnail. Target custom css to specific permalink

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm trying to customize my tumblr video thumbnails so I can target a specific image to every video post.

The HTML the code is:

```
{block:Video}
    <div class="media-embed">
        {block:IndexPage}
            <script class="template-replace" type="text/template">
                {VideoEmbed-700}
            </script>
            <div class="video-thumbnail template-remove"{block:VideoThumbnail} style="background-image:url({VideoThumbnailURL});"{/block:VideoThumbnail}></div>
        {/block:IndexPage}
        {block:PermalinkPage}
            {VideoEmbed-700}
        {/block:PermalinkPage}
        {block:IndexPage}
            <div class="video button-overlay {select:Button colors} template-remove"></div>
        {/block:IndexPage}
    </div>
    {block:Caption}
        <div class="caption">
            {Caption}
                {block:More}{block:IfReadMoreText}<p class="read-more-text"><a href="{Permalink}">{text:Read More Text}</a></p>{/block:IfReadMoreText}{/block:More}
        </div>
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Video}
```

I think I should replace the `style="background-image:url({VideoThumbnailURL})` but I can't figure out what code I should replace it with.
Any thoughts?
Thanks!
B

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{block:VideoThumbnail}
{VideoThumbnailURL}
{/block:VideoThumbnail}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into the **{TagsAsClasses}** variable.

```
 <div class="video-thumbnail template-remove {TagsAsClasses}"{block:VideoThumbnail} style="background-image:url({VideoThumbnailURL});"{/block:VideoThumbnail}></div>
```

You can tag each video post with a unique tag and then simply style it with css.

```
.thumbnailtest {
/* add your styles here */
 }
```